# How to rotate gradient using SVG.js?

Tags: javascript, svg, gradient

How to rotate gradient using SVG.js?
I tried

```
var gradient = draw.gradient('linear', function(stop) {
    stop.at(0, '#f2b181')
    stop.at(1, '#de6d1e')
}).rotate(45);
```

but with no effect.

Answer (score 3):

Linear gradients can be rotated by using the `from()` and `to()` methods. So to achieve a 45 degrees rotation, your code would be:

```
var gradient = draw.gradient('linear', function(stop) {
  stop.at(0, '#f2b181')
  stop.at(1, '#de6d1e')
}).from(0, 0).to(1, 1)
```

Here is a fiddle so you can play with it:
http://jsfiddle.net/wout/ZhsFD/

But I can see the need for the `rotate()` method, it would be a nice addition to the api. I will include it in the next release.

Comment: Did this ever get added to the API? I don't see it in the docs.

Comment: Yes, it's all there. http://svgjs.com/elements/#gradient-from and http://svgjs.com/elements/#gradient-to